# Get count of exact word match within a Text file

Tags: powershell

The requirement is to get the exact match count for a word "test". So in the following example it should be 1:

```text
testing 1 2 3 "test" testing
Tester testing 2345 tes testers testings testing
test
```

I tried the below code :

```
(Get-Content "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\POC\Findstring.txt" | 
    Select-String -Pattern "test" -AllMatches).matches.count
```

But it provides me the value as 9 since it provides a like functionality (it is also considering tester,testing etc in the count).

How should we ensure that we get the count for exact match and not for a LIKE operator scenario (similar to in SQL).

Comment: Try `"\btest\b"` to enclose the word you'r after in word boundaries. P.S. It would have been better if you had added the test file as formatted TEXT instead of an image..

Comment: As said, `\b` is the regex word boundary with which you make sure you are testing for a whole word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Use regex `\btest\b` as the `-Pattern` argument so as to match `test` as a *whole word* only.
- Pass your input file path directly to `Select-String`'s `-LiteralPath` parameter, which is much faster and more efficient than streaming the individual lines from the file via `Get-Content`.

```bash
(
  Select-String -AllMatches `
                -Pattern '\btest\b' `
                -LiteralPath C:\Users\abc\Desktop\POC\Findstring.txt 
).Matches.Count
```

<sup>Note: The command is spread across multiple lines for readability. To convert it to a single-line form, also remove the line-ending `` ` `` (backtick) characters, which act as line continuations.</sup>

---

Your intent is to limit matching `test` substrings to *whole words*.

Since [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) uses [regexes (regular expressions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), you can do so by enclosing the substring in *word-boundary assertions*, `\b`, as [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) advises, i.e. `'\btest\b'`

- For a detailed explanation of this regex and the ability to interact with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/OT2qVw/1)

Also note that `Select-String` - like PowerShell in general - is case-*insensitive* by default; to match case-sensitively, add the `-CaseSensitive` switch.

---

**Variation with also ignoring the word `test` when enclosed in `"..."`**

If you additionally want to ignore `"test"` substrings (i.e. double-quoted instances of the word), you must amend your regex to also include a *negative look-behind assertion*, `(?!...)` in order to preclude a `"` preceding the word:

```bash
(
  Select-String -AllMatches `
                -Pattern '(?<!")\btest\b' `
                -LiteralPath C:\Users\abc\Desktop\POC\Findstring.txt 
).Matches.Count
```

See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/OT2qVw/2).

Comment: Hey @mkelement() Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. I have updated my scenario a little wherein I have added double quotes in 1 case of test word and have kept the others same. Now In case I need to cheek for the test word explicitly , ideally the value should be 1 but in this case I am still getting 2 whereas with the scenario provided by Toni I am getting the desired output. Can you please suggest can we handle this with current : -Pattern '\btest\b'   approach

Comment: @Nandan, please see my update. Note that Toni's answer is quite inefficient, and I wouldn't recommend such techniques in general. (As stated, if you wanted to tokenize the entire file first, `((-split (Get-Content -Raw C:\tmp\testdata.txt)) -eq 'test').Count` is an efficient formulation.) In general, please don't change the requirements after answers have already been given, as doing so may invalidate them - ask a _new_ question instead (not necessary in this case).

Comment: Thank you @mklement0. This is very helpful. Now just out of curiosity in case if I needed to search "test"  value appearance count ,  what aspect would I have to consider

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Nandan. If you want to search for `"test"` verbatim (including the double quotes), use `'"test"'`

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you search for the pattern `test` which is also true in case of `testing`, `testers`, etc. The following should do the trick:

```
((Get-Content "C:\tmp\testdata.txt") -split " " | Select-String -Pattern '^(test)$' -AllMatches).count
```

Comment: Thank you. This did work out but can you signify what does ^ and $ at the start and end of the pattern value signify

Comment: ^ = specifies the beginning of the string
$ = specifies the end of the string

see anchors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: While this technically works, it is needlessly complicated and inefficient: It reads the file line by line, splits each line into tokens, then feeds the token individually to `Select-String`.
If you wanted to go this route, `((-split (Get-Content -Raw C:\tmp\testdata.txt)) -eq 'test').Count` is a much faster and more efficient formulation.
However, there's is no need to read the file in full and split it into tokens first, given that a single `Select-String` call with a word-boundary assertion, `\b`, will do, and that you can pass the file _path_ directly to `Select-String`